# Connection string to a remote DB2 db in another server

Tags: c, db2

I'm trying to figure out the connection string to connect to a remote DB2 using the C DB2 API (and odbc).
So far I've tried with different options without success.
The documentation is not clear at the second parameter of SQLConnect when defining the data base name.

```
SQLConnect(hdbc, "hostname/dbname", SQL_NTS, "user", SQL_NTS, "pass", SQL_NTS);
SQLConnect(hdbc, "hostname:dbname", SQL_NTS, "user", SQL_NTS, "pass", SQL_NTS);

// just as jdbc format...
SQLConnect(hdbc, "odbc:db2://hostname/dbname", SQL_NTS, "user", SQL_NTS, "pass", SQL_NTS);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQLConnect()` function doesn't allow you to specify remote host details in the `ServerName` parameter. You can only specify a database alias name here.  If the database is on a remote server, you need to set up the connection parameters via the DB2 client (using the `catalog node` and `catalog database` commands).

However, you can use the [`SQLDriverConnect()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000584.html) function and specify full details in the connection string like you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks!, the SQLDriverConnect() function was the answer to my problems. Basically for a DB2 connection I used the following configuration (it's the second parameter of the function):   `"Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC Driver};Database=testDb;Hostname=remoteHostName.com;UID=username;PWD=mypasswd;PORT=50000"`